# Сортировка таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, битрикс

Если я хочу отсортировать либо по коду, либо по описанию, либо по фирме- то сортировка идет по всем полям.
Если я хочу отсортировать либо по цене, либо по сроку поставки, либо по нал. - то сортировка идет внутри объединенного блока.
Храню данные в json (ид товара, кол-во потомков, ид потомка, фирма, код, описание, нал., срок поставки, цена).В плане отправить json на сервер ajax запросом и возвращать готовую html таблицу отсортированную. Вопрос, как отсортировать на сервере?  Что надо использовать?
Пример таблицы: http://prntscr.com/980y42
Данные у меня битриксовые, используется шаблон компоненты, то есть никакого подключения к базе нет, то есть сам шаблон все делает. Битриксовская сортировка мне не подходит в силу того, что каждому покупателю показываются одни данные, другому другие данные, то есть решается в индивидуальном порядке для каждого клиента.

Вот код компоненты catalog_section

```html
<table class="definition-table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
                    <th class="def-table-code"><a href="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB&amp;sort=property_CML2_ARTICLE&amp;method=asc">Код</a></th>
                    <th class="def-table-manufacturer"><a href="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB&amp;sort=property_BREND&amp;method=asc">Производитель</a></th>
                    <th class="def-table-title"><a href="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB&amp;sort=NAME&amp;method=asc">Название</a></th>
                    <th class="def-table-available"><a href="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB&amp;sort=CATALOG_QUANTITY&amp;method=asc">Количество, шт.</a></th>
                    <th class="def-table-delivery"><a href="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB&amp;sort=property_CML2_DAYS_DELIVERY&amp;method=asc">Срок поставки, дн.</a></th>
                    <th class="def-table-price"><a href="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB&amp;sort=CATALOG_PRICE_1&amp;method=asc">Цена, руб.</a></th>
                    <th class="def-table-buy">В корзину</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="main-tr"><td colspan="7">Результаты для запрошенного номера</td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="3">333741</td>
     <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="3">KYB</td>
     <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="3">Амортизатор подвески передн DACIA: LOGAN 04-</td>
     
     <td class="def-table-available W">20 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery W">1</td>  
     <td class="def-table-price W">
      2 245.69  
     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy W">
             <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix"> 
                   
          <div class="counter">
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 20) this.value=20" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity465828"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter">
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity465828').value < 20) BX('quantity465828').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity465828').value > 1) BX('quantity465828').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (20 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card465828">
          </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="465828"> 
        <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;">           
       </form>
           </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="def-table-available W">100 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery W">1</td>
     <td class="def-table-price W">
      2 239.72     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy W">
                               <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix">
                   <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 100) this.value=100" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity532351"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter"> 
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity532351').value < 100) BX('quantity532351').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity532351').value > 1) BX('quantity532351').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                        <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (100 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card532351">
                                        </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="532351"> 
                                <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;"> 
       </form>
           </td>
    </tr>
   
        <tr>
          <td class="def-table-available W">100 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery W">1</td>
     <td class="def-table-price W">
      2 245.79     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy W">
                               <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix">
                   <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 100) this.value=100" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity465829"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter"> 
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity465829').value < 100) BX('quantity465829').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity465829').value > 1) BX('quantity465829').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                        <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (100 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card465829">
                                        </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="465829"> 
                                <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;"> 
       </form>
           </td>
    </tr>
   
    
<tr class="main-tr"><td colspan="7">Аналоги для запрошенного номера</td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="2">ASH7072</td>
     <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="2">AUTOMOTOR FRANCE</td>
     <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="2">Амортизатор RENAULT LOGAN 04- зад.масл.</td>
     
     <td class="def-table-available N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">3 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">На складе</td>  
     <td class="def-table-price N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">
      1 250.26  
     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">
             <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix"> 
                  
          <div class="counter">
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 3) this.value=3" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity120608"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter">
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity120608').value < 3) BX('quantity120608').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity120608').value > 1) BX('quantity120608').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (3 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card120608">
          </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="120608"> 
        <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;">           
       </form>
           </td>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
           <td class="def-table-available W">2 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery W">1</td>
     <td class="def-table-price W">
      2 051.05     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy W">
                               <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix">
                   <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 2) this.value=2" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity350832"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter"> 
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity350832').value < 2) BX('quantity350832').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity350832').value > 1) BX('quantity350832').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (2 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card350832">
                                                                                </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="350832"> 
                                <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;"> 
       </form>
           </td>
    </tr>
   
        <tr>
     <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="2">ASG7072</td>
     <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="2">AUTOMOTOR FRANCE</td>
     <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="2">Амортизатор RENAULT LOGAN 04- зад.газ.</td>
     
     <td class="def-table-available N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">2 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">На складе</td>  
     <td class="def-table-price N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">
      1 250.26  
     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">
             <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix"> 
                  
          <div class="counter">
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 2) this.value=2" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity120606"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter">
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity120606').value < 2) BX('quantity120606').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity120606').value > 1) BX('quantity120606').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (2 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card120606">
          </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="120606"> 
        <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;">           
       </form>
           </td>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
           <td class="def-table-available W">5 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery W">1</td>
     <td class="def-table-price W">
      1 419.67     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy W">
                               <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix">
                   <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 5) this.value=5" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity350831"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter"> 
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity350831').value < 5) BX('quantity350831').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity350831').value > 1) BX('quantity350831').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (5 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card350831">
                                                                                </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="350831"> 
                                <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;"> 
       </form>
           </td>
    </tr>
   
        <tr>
     <td class="def-table-code" rowspan="2">PSA333741</td>
     <td class="def-table-manufacturer" rowspan="2">PATRON</td>
     <td class="def-table-title" rowspan="2">Амортизатор подвески передн DACIA: LOGAN 04-</td>
     
     <td class="def-table-available N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">2 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">На складе</td>  
     <td class="def-table-price N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">
      1 544.33  
     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy N" style="background-color: rgb(200, 255, 200);">
             <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix"> 
                  
          <div class="counter">
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 2) this.value=2" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity86753"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter">
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity86753').value < 2) BX('quantity86753').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity86753').value > 1) BX('quantity86753').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (2 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card86753">
          </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="86753"> 
        <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;">           
       </form>
           </td>
        </tr>
         <tr> 
           <td class="def-table-available W">100 </td>
     <td class="def-table-delivery W">1</td>
     <td class="def-table-price W">
      1 431.21     </td>
     <td class="def-table-buy W">
                               <form action="/ino/index.php?q=333741&amp;brand=KYB" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix">
                   <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value > 100) this.value=100" name="quantity" value="1" id="quantity350655"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter"> 
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity350655').value < 100) BX('quantity350655').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('quantity350655').value > 1) BX('quantity350655').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter"> 
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (100 > 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="actionADD2BASKET" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card350655">
                                                                                </div>
                 </div>
        <div class="some-class">
                 </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="BUY"> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="350655"> 
                                <input type="submit" name="actionBUY" value="Купить" style="display:none;"> 
       </form>
           </td>
    </tr>
   
       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Эту html таблицу формирует php код компоненты битрикса.
У меня это одна таблица , но нужно отсортировать в пределах результатов запрошенного номера и аналогов запрошенного номера отдельно. (то есть из одной таблички нужно отсортировать две отдельные таблички).Я формирую массив (ид товара, кол-во потомков, ид потомка, фирма, код, описание, нал., срок поставки, цена) в виде

```html
  <?
                                    $row_section[$index]['id']=$productID;
                                    $row_section[$index]['cell']=array($tovar,$cnt,$productID,$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_ARTICLE"]["VALUE"],$arElement["PROPERTIES"]["BREND"]["VALUE"],$arElement["NAME"],$n,$arOffer["PROPERTIES"]["CML2_DAYS_DELIVERY"]["VALUE"],$price);
                                    $index=$index+1;
                                    ?>
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос, приведите примеры кода, что вы подразумеваете под "отсортировать на сервере", может у вас там SQL база данных, например, а SQL базы все отлично сортируют

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на описание селекта айблоков:

```
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php
```

Вот описание этого селекта:

```
    CIBlockResult
    CIBlockElement::GetList(
     array arOrder = Array("SORT"=>"ASC"),
     array arFilter = Array(),
     mixed arGroupBy = false,
     mixed arNavStartParams = false,
     array arSelectFields = Array()
    );
```

Видимо, нужно указывать параметр arGroupBy, например

```
$arSelect = Array("ID", "IBLOCK_ID", "NAME", "CODE", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_*", "DETAIL_TEXT");
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>15, "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("CODE"), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
...
}
```